# Convex hull is a subset of the numerical range

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

**Question** Show that if A is a normal matrix, then W(A) (the numerical range of A) is the convex hull of the eigenvalues of A.
**Progress** I have proved that the W(A) ⊆ conv A similar to [Numerical range of a normal matrix is the convex hull of its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022418/numerical-range-of-a-normal-matrix-is-the-convex-hull-of-its-eigenvalues). But I am unsure of how to prove that the conv A ⊆ W(A).
I  have started with a convex combination and sort of  am trying to work backwards from what I have  and letting v=(Sqrt(t1), ..., Sqrt(tn)), but I do not know how to finish this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $l = \sum_k t_k \lambda_k $ where $t_k \ge0 $ and $\sum_k t_k = 1$. Since $A$ is normal, we can write $A=U \Lambda U^*$ where $U$ is unitary and $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Let $x=U(\sqrt{t_1},...,\sqrt{t_n})$, then
$x^* A x = l$.